# Admob banner ad displaying white, expo on Android

Tags: android, react-native, admob, expo

I can't seem to get Admob banners to display anything except a white box. I can confirm that the adUnitID is correct and the ad unit is enabled. My app.json android part:

```
"android": {
  "config": {
    "googleMobileAdsAppId": "xxx"
  },
  "package": "xxx",
  "versionCode": 1
},
```

And here is the Admob banner component within my app.js:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
    <AppNavigator />
    <View style={styles.adContainer}>
      <AdMobBanner
        bannerSize='fullBanner'
        adUnitId='xxx'
        onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={() => console.log('error')}
        servePersonalizedAds
      />
    </View> 
 </View>

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
   },
   adContainer: {
     borderColor: 'red',
     borderWidth: 1,
   },
 });
```

Looking at the logs, it never actually prints out "error." I put the border around the ad container to confirm that it is being displayed, if I change the bannerSize prop I can see it changing size so it is allocating the space for the banner correctly. This is Expo SDK version 37.0.10 and I've only tested on an Android physical device. When I create an apk it similarly shows the banner as only white.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I add banner in expo easy

in app.js

```
 import { AdMobBanner,} from 'expo-ads-admob';

 <AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="banner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-yourKeyHere" 
  servePersonalizedAds={false}
  onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
```

in app.json

```
 "android": {
 
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-yourKeyHere"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding a `View` around your `Ad-mob` tag and give it a border width and color of border width it should highlight your ad.

```
<View style={{borderWidth : 2 ,borderColor : 'orange'}}>
....
</View>
```